# Chunked Encoding Implementation in .NET (or at least pseudo code)

Tags: .net, http, encoding, tcp, chunked-encoding

I wrote a raw TCP client for HTTP/HTTPS requests, however I'm having problems with chunked encoding responses. HTTP/1.1 is requirement therefore I should support it.

*Raw TCP is a business requirement that I need to keep, therefore I can't switch to .NET HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse* However if there is way to convert a RAW HTTP Request/Response into HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse that'd work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to start is the [http 1.1 specification](ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc2616.txt), which lays out how chunking works. Specifically section 3.6.1.

> 3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding
>
> The chunked encoding modifies the
>   body of a message in order to
>   transfer it as a series of chunks,
>   each with its own size indicator,
>   followed by an OPTIONAL trailer
>   containing entity-header fields. This 
>   allows dynamically produced content to
>   be transferred along with the
>   information necessary for the
>   recipient to verify that it has
>   received the full message.
>
> ```
>    Chunked-Body   = *chunk
>                     last-chunk
>                     trailer
>                     CRLF
>
>    chunk          = chunk-size [ chunk-extension ] CRLF
>                     chunk-data CRLF
>    chunk-size     = 1*HEX
>    last-chunk     = 1*("0") [ chunk-extension ] CRLF
>
>    chunk-extension= *( ";" chunk-ext-name [ "=" chunk-ext-val ] )
>    chunk-ext-name = token
>    chunk-ext-val  = token | quoted-string
>    chunk-data     = chunk-size(OCTET)
>    trailer        = *(entity-header CRLF)
> ```
>
> The chunk-size field is a string of
>   hex digits indicating the size of
>   the chunk. The chunked encoding is
>   ended by any chunk whose size is
>   zero, followed by the trailer, which
>   is terminated by an empty line.
>
> The trailer allows the sender to
>   include additional HTTP header
>   fields at the end of the message. The
>   Trailer header field can be    used to
>   indicate which header fields are
>   included in a trailer (see    section
>   14.40).

Assuming that you have already read the header from the response and are pointing to the next byte in the stream your pseudo code would look something like this:

```
done = false;
uint8 bytes[];
while (!done)
{
  chunksizeString = readuntilCRLF(); // read in the chunksize as a string
  chunksizeString.strip(); // strip off the CRLF
  chunksize = chunksizeString.convertHexString2Int(); // convert the hex string to an integer.
  bytes.append(readXBytes(chunksize)); // read in the x bytes and append them to your buffer.
  readCRLF(); // read the trailing CRLF and throw it away.
  if (chunksize == 0)
     done = true; //

}
// now read the trailer if any
// trailer is optional, so it may be just the empty string
trailer = readuntilCRLF()
trailer = trailer.strip()
if (trailer != "")
   readCRLF(); // read out the last CRLF and we are done.
```

This is ignoring the chunk-extension portion, but since it is delimited with a ";" it should be easy to split it out. This should be enough to get you started. Keep in mind that the chunksize string **does not** have a leading "0x".

Answer (score 1):

For the future reference also I found this :

```
 length := 0
   read chunk-size, chunk-extension (if any) and CRLF
   while (chunk-size > 0) {
      read chunk-data and CRLF
      append chunk-data to entity-body
      length := length + chunk-size
      read chunk-size and CRLF
   }
   read entity-header
   while (entity-header not empty) {
      append entity-header to existing header fields
      read entity-header
   }
   Content-Length := length
   Remove "chunked" from Transfer-Encoding
```